# How to import JS Library in Flutter App/Web?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to import the following file in flutter and use their functions.

```
<script src="https://assets.pagseguro.com.br/checkout-sdk-js/rc/dist/browser/pagseguro.min.js"></script>
```

and then call a function that encrypts a data card

```
var card = PagSeguro.encryptCard({
  publicKey: "MINHA_CHAVE_PUBLICA",
  holder: "Nome Sobrenome",
  number: "4242424242424242",
  expMonth: "12",
  expYear: "2030",
  securityCode: "123"
});

var encrypted = card.encryptedCard;
```

I need this encrypted card data, to send through an API and process a purchase.
This package is the only way that company gives to encrypt its card data

Answer (score 2):

from dart [documention](https://dart.dev/web/js-interop), you just can't use javascript code on platforms but the web.

dart compiles to native code.

on the web, you can use the [js package](https://pub.dev/packages/js)

Comment: There's another way to import this file and use their functions?

Comment: now saying that you want to use javascript code inside dart code, and you can't without that dart.dev js package which it let you do it

Comment: But this will work only in the Web version or App too?

Comment: no, only the web, but out of the box you can make that feature in a simple web app, and embed it inside your mobile flutter app, but using javascript directly with the dart code is impossible for android and IOS since flutter turn all the dart code to native arm x86/x64 code

Comment: so to recap, you can make that feature in a separate web app and then embed it inside your flutter apps like a review, or you can search an API that you can get/post values from/to it to get results of what you need, and I can think of another thing is to make a cloud function like the firebase cloud functions or any other services to run that methods in the cloud

Comment: Can you send me some examples of how to implement this embedded web app?

Comment: here is a package from the official flutter team, the https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter you can show a website or localhost inside your application, check it